# Flutter: 'WebViewPlatform.instance != null' in Windows application

Tags: flutter

I am learning the webViewWidget with the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview#3), and having trouble using the widget. In particular, how can I handle webViewWidget when targeting the Windows app? The error goes away when using Android Emulator.

It's intuitive since I can implement RWD at the same time. However, reading through the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter), I don't see the specific settings to resolve the issue.

Here is the code snippet from the codelab:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'),
      ); // error when instantiating the WebViewController in Windows app
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What does "implement RWD" mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. RWD stands for responsive web design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error when instantiating the WebViewController in Windows app

...that's because Flutter's `webview_flutter` doesn't support Windows. [The documentation you linked to](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) says it only supports Android and iOS:

[image]

Comment: yes, I understand that it doesn't support it. Since I am building a website and app altogether, sometimes I want to make sure the wrapper layout, which is on top of web_view is positioning okay.

Comment: For example, I used the first flutter app also from the codelab (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#8) to wrap the `web_view` within another page.

Comment: I understand now. I appreciate your patience.